# Eclipse CDT, how to build with Gstreamer?

Tags: eclipse-cdt, gstreamer

I am new at BigCompany and have been given a subsystem & told to build it under Linux, since I was dumb enough to suggest unit test (there has never been a unit test & all builds are currently for an ARM processor).

Some code, which no one knows anything about, uses GStreamer. It has statements like

```
#include "gst/gst.h"
#include "gst/gsttaglist.h"
```

which give the GCC error

```
fatal error: gst/gst.h: No such file or directory
```

I grepped and found it in

> /opt/tooling/imx6-staging/DI_BINARY_REPOSITORY_IMX6_LINUX_14.0F46/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10/gst/gst.h

so I went to project Properties/C & C++ General/paths and symbols and added

> /opt/tooling/imx6-staging/DI_BINARY_REPOSITORY_IMX6_LINUX_14.0F46/usr/include/gstreamer-0.10

to the path. The error persisted.

I also tried adding `gstreamer-0.10` to the libraries, but to no avail.

How do I get this to compile in Eclipse CDT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing the right thing, and what Scooter describes is correct.  However I'd add that in my experience, tracking down all the GStreamer and GLib paths is a pain and it always seemed like Eclipse didn't like when I added them manually.

For our Eclipse/GStreamer projects the build tool we find most useful is CMake.  It's a Makefile make tool that offers Eclipse project file generation also.  So in a file CMakeLists.txt we'd have something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(myproj)

include(FindPkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-app-1.0)
pkg_check_modules(LIBLOG4CXX REQUIRED liblog4cxx)

include_directories(${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${LIBLOG4CXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GST_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${LIBLOG4CXX_LIBRARY_DIRS})

add_executable(myproj myproj.cpp)

target_link_libraries(myproj ${GST_LIBRARIES} ${LIBLOG4CXX_LIBRARIES})
```

Then from the command line, I point the environment to whatever pkg-config path I'm using and run cmake.

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/whatever/pkgconfig
cmake --clean-first . -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
```

Now open up the project in Eclipse.  You may have to Index->Rebuild but after that it works great in my experience.

Another benefit of this is if you're working on a team project you don't have to create the Eclipse project files from hand for each project member, or try to share machine-specific project files across users.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to add Include Paths and Include Files to a project:

Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build ->  Settings -> Tool Settings tab -> Includes -> Include files/paths -> Add... (via the icon)

Comment: yup, I tried that - although I arrived there by a different path. It didn't help. Until I find a solution, I have imported the entire gst source into my project, but I obviously don't want to do that long term.

Comment: @Mawg Did you try Project->C/C++ Index-> [Re-resolve Unresolved Includes, Search for Unresolved Includes]

Comment: Also worth trying Index->Rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the h files, go to Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Cross GCC Linker->Libraries. Press the add button and input your library name : "gstreamer-0.10". 
Hope this helps.